# In Flutter using signalr_netcore package, how do you handle backend restart?

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, signalr

I implemented several hubs from my asp.net core 7 backend such as general notifications and chat messages.
Everything is working as expected except the case where I power off my backend and power it on again.

My client logs shows server pings before the connection lost, then shows connection lost, then it enters the reconnection feature from the flutter signalr package and succeed in doing so with a new connection id. It then logs the new pings received from the server as if everything is working again.

However hubs related features starts to become erratic and after some time I get a 'Connection timed out' _ClientSocketException on a call for the hub's /*negociate* endpoint internally called by the http client of the signalr package.

It has been 4 days trying to understand what could be the proper way to handling reconnection after the backend restarts without success.

If anyone have faced this situation and can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: My answer is not based on flutter, I'm just explaining the retry mechanism and the way to resubscribe the methods, which would be very effective.

Comment: You also could share your client side sample code, I could try to help you write a sample for you to test when I am free next week. You can implement it by yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem can be solved by adding a retry mechanism.

Reason: Assuming that the signalr client is coded in Javascript or C# client, after the signalr server is disconnected, you only need to ensure that the signalr client runs stably and wait for the signalr server to return to normal.

**Here is the sample code** (*Javascript*)

```
let retryCount = 0;

let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/yourHub")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

// you can put the methods here
function subscribeToMethods() {
    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
        console.log("Message received:", message);
    });
}
// this is important,This prevents connections 
//that have already been created from being destroyed. 
subscribeToMethods();

connection.onclose(async (error) => {
    console.log("Connection lost:", error);
    attemptReconnect();
});

connection.onreconnected((connectionId) => {
    console.log("Reconnected. Connection Id: " + connectionId);
    subscribeToMethods();
});

async function startConnection() {
    try {
        await connection.start();
        console.log("SignalR Connected");
        retryCount = 0;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("SignalR Connection Failed: ", err);
        attemptReconnect();
    }
}

function attemptReconnect() {
    let retryDuration;
    if (retryCount < 12) {
        if (retryCount < 12) {
            // 5s, 15s, 30s, 1m, 2m
            const backoffStrategy = [5000, 15000, 30000, 60000, 120000];
            retryDuration = backoffStrategy[Math.min(retryCount, backoffStrategy.length - 1)];
        }
    } else {
        // After approximately an hour, use the same backoff strategy
        const backoffStrategy = [5000, 15000, 30000, 60000, 120000];
        retryDuration = backoffStrategy[backoffStrategy.length - 1];
    }
    console.log(`Attempt to reconnect in ${retryDuration} ms`);
    setTimeout(() => startConnection(), retryDuration);
    retryCount++;
}

startConnection();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I am not looking for reconnection code as mine is already doing so. As I mentioned, the reconnection happens and I do receive the ping messages from the server with the new connection id. In the same time an async call to the signalr /negociate endpoint seams to still be pending and it triggers the exception I detailed. It may be related to the flutter package.